# Unable to execute a file in linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fopen, file-handling

I have created a program in which `fopen()` is being used. For Ex:-

```
int main() {
    FILE* check=NULL;
    check=fopen("C:\\Files\\open.txt","rb");
    if(check==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Error";
    }
    else
    {
        //do something
    }
    
}
```

Now, in the above program windows path is working properly i.e. `"C:\\Files\\open.txt"` but when i try to execute the same program in wsl(linux) by changing the path to `/mnt/c/Files/open.txt`, I am getting error. I am not sure if setting up path this way is the standard procedure for `fopen()` in linux. **Please suggest me something to overcome this error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `perror("fopen")` to the main function and please share the output. It is difficult to answer this question without the output.

I think the problem may be:
You don't have permission to access `/mnt` or no such file or that file doesn't have read permission... etc.

Comment: It says `fopen: No such file or directory` but the file is there when i checked using `ls`. Am i giving path wrongly? Also, in windows, it says `fopen: No error`

Comment: Note that linux is case sensitive, so `files` and `Files` are not equal.

Comment: How about `cat /mnt/c/Files/open.txt`?